# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? using Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zepto

I'm using Zurb Foundation and am getting the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

From this block of code:

```
<script>
    document.write('<script src=http://[mydomain]/js/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in  ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>
```

The code appears to be in accordance with Zurb's documentation. Is this error something to be concerned about? If so, what could I do to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a variable in the below line:

```
+ ('__proto__' in  ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
```

Should have been something like below:

```
+ ('__proto__' in myObject ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
```